# Spring MVC 3: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using Spring MVC 3 to setup and process a form but I am having this problem that I never had before while submitting a form using Spring MVC 3 and I am not able to understand the reason behind it.

When I submit the form I get an **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported** error.
Following is the .jsp form and controller I am using to get it working.

**newProblem.jsp**

```
<form:form  commandName="problem" >
        <form:label path="problem" >
            <span class="label">Problem <form:errors path="problem" /></span>
        </form:label>
        <form:textarea path="problem" cssClass="editor"  id="editor"/>


        <input type="submit" value="create"  />
</form:form>
```

**ProblemManagementController.java**

```
//Add new problem (GET)
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/admin/problems/new")
public String setUpForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("problem", new Problem());
    return "newProblem";
}

//Add new problem (POST)
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/admin/problems/new")
public String processForm(@Valid Problem problem, Errors result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "newProblem";
    }
    problemManagementService.createProblem(problem);
    return "redirect:/admin/problems";
}

//Display all problems
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/problems")
public String displayAllProblems(Model model) {
    List<Problem> allProblems = problemManagementService.getAllProblems();

    model.addAttribute("allProblems", allProblems);
    return "allProblems";
}
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error?

Comment: For some reasons Eclipse IDE was not reading `processForm` and `displayAllProblems` methods. After cleaning the server and project and then redeploying the project to server got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add action in `<form:form>` tag.

try this one :

```
<form:form action="admin/problems/new" commandName="problem" >
        <form:label path="problem" >
            <span class="label">Problem <form:errors path="problem" /></span>
        </form:label>
        <form:textarea path="problem" cssClass="editor"  id="editor"/>


        <input type="submit" value="create"  />
</form:form>
```